# Can I use the Helvetica font in a commercial iOS app that I am building without a license?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, fonts

I have my application (I am an iOS developer) which I want to publish on Appstore, so I want it to be commercial.

I am using Helvetica font in the application. what kind of rights have external customers have for it?

Do I need to buy this font, or can I use it for free, when the application is for iOS, in which this font is used?

How does it look like in law glance?

Comment: Maybe this question would work better in https://law.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a question about licensing, not a question about programming. Licensing questions can be asked on https://law.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Six fonts from the Helvetica family are included among the [system fonts in macOS and iOS](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/system-fonts/). All devices will have these fonts. You don't need a special license to use the font in your app, or for users to format their own content using them. But you would not be able to redistribute the fonts or use them for versions of your app on other platforms (unless they are included as system fonts in the other platforms).